# Create Rank and Order for Calendar Month and Year Combination in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a date table that has 1 row for every date starting in 1980.  This table also includes Calendar Month and Calendar Year columns.  I need to create a row number that puts 1 value for each calendar month and year combination in the calendar month/year order.

Here is an example table:

```
DateID | Date | MonthCode | MonthName | Year
1 | 01/01/1980 | 1 | Jan | 1980
2 | 01/02/1980 | 1 | Jan | 1980
...
828 | 04/07/1982 | 4 | Apr | 1982
```

I need a value that is unique for every month/year combination

```
Jan 1980 | 1
Jan 1980 | 1
Feb 1980 | 2
Feb 1980 | 2
```

This would need to be in calendar order and year order.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work right:

```
dense_rank() OVER(partition by calendarMonthName order by  CalendarMonth, calendaryear asc) AS YearMonthRowID
```

This results in a rank that restarts every month and is in alphabetical order

Any help on getting this formatted correctly?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by year, monthcode)
from t
```

Comment: Ahhh!  It was so much simpler than I thought.  Thank you!